# MS Access query with no duplicates

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I'm working on building a query where it doesn't allow for duplicates. I've built a task/time manager and in the table for it I created a column called "Active". It's a true/false switch that signifies if an employee is busy or free. I'm now building a query where I want it to show if "active" switch is true then it shows as "Busy" otherwise if it's false they are "Free". I can get this to work but it shows duplicates. In the table I do have it indexed to not show duplicates but I'm still getting them.

Here is the SQL View:

```
 `SELECT Employees.Employee
 , IIf([Active]=True,"Unavailable","Free") AS Avail
 FROM tblTasks INNER JOIN Employees ON tblTasks.[User ID] = Employees.UserID;`
```

This is the current setup:
[image: CurrentSetup]

And this is the current output:

[image: Output]

Ultimately the goal is to get it so that if any employee has a "True" flag on the "Active" field then they appear once as "Unavailable" but if they have all "False" tags on the Active field they appear once as "Available".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the SQL generated by Access.

Comment: You'll get duplicates because your query will return results for each `tblTask` row instead of for each `Employee` row. What should happen if the same employee has multiple `tblTask` rows with different `Active` values?

Comment: If any employee has a true in the "active" field I want it to show them as unavailable, but if they have all false I want them to show as available. That's the goal

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer... still waiting for caffeine to kick in. The goal is that if someone, using Damian for example, has the true flag in the active field on any record; so he has "Free" and "Unavailable" he is considered unavailable, even though he has one row that says he is free. True trumps False. Hopefully that helps clear it up a little?

Comment: @KenWhite edit made. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

```
SELECT Employees.UserID, Employee, IIf(CntTrue>0, "Unavailable", "Available") AS Status 
FROM Employees 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS CntTrue, UserID FROM tblTasks 
           WHERE Active = True GROUP BY UserID) AS Q1 
ON Employees.UserID = Q1.UserID;
```

or

```
SELECT Employees.*, IIf(Q1.UserID Is Null, "Available", "UnAvailable") AS Status 
FROM Employees 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblTasks WHERE Active = True) AS Q1 
ON Employees.UserID = Q1.UserID;
```

or

`SELECT UserID, Employee, IIf(DCount("*","tblTasks","Active=True AND UserID=" & [UserID])>0, "Unavailable", "Available") AS Status FROM Employees;`

Note use of LEFT JOIN to assure all employees are returned. INNER JOIN would exclude employees who are not assigned a task. Perhaps all employees have at least one task but this allows for possibility some don't.

Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.
Should probably designate UserID in Employees as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select 
  e.employee,
  max(iif(t.active, "Unavailable", "Free"))
from Employees e inner join tblTasks t
on t.userid = e.userid
group by e.userid, e.employee
```

since the string `"Unavailable"` is greater than the string `"Free"` (or `"Available"`). 
 If you choose different strings to denote availability, you will have to adjust.
So if you choose `"Busy"` and `"Free"` then you must change to:

```
select 
  e.employee,
  min(iif(t.active, "Busy", "Free"))
from Employees e inner join tblTasks t
on t.userid = e.userid
group by e.userid, e.employee
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found something which may make it easier. In the query using "design view" right-click on the upper portion of the query (where the tables you draw from are located) and pull up the "properties". In the properties box (usually located on the right side change "Unique Values" to yes. Let us know if this works for you.